# how to get saved image from document folder and show image on next visit of url not from parsecd image

Tags: iphone, ios

I have one application in that i want to store icons image from from online image path (url) in local.

i store this image in local when user visit another url the icon was replacing with previous and how replace this icon for reuse plz help me out.

thank you!

```
        NSString *strImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aBook.image];
        NSURL *url4Image = [NSURL URLWithString:strImage];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url4Image];
        if(data !=NULL)
        {
            imageView =[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            if(imageView == NULL)
            {
                imageView =[UIImage imageNamed:@"dealsbell_lo.png"];    //  NoImage.png

            }
        }
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView);
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.png"];
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];

        cell.imageView.image = imageView;
```

Answer (score 0):

For such scenario, you should be caching the downloaded images and resume the same for next request.

I think you should use [JMImageCache](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache) framework for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%d.png",indexPath.row]];//change name of image
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPathToFile])
    {
        NSData *imgData  = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPathToFile];
        if(imgData){
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        cellimageView.image = img;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       NSString *strImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aBook.image];
       NSURL *url4Image = [NSURL URLWithString:strImage];
       NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url4Image];
       if(imgData){
       UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
       cellimageView.image = img;
       [data writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
       }
    }
```